# consoletvs v6 charts X axes : is it possible to have date (or timestamp) with irregular ticks?

Tags: laravel, charts, graphics, continuous, quantitative

I'm trying to create X axes that considerate date as value so that ticks will be irregular, here is my chart options :

```
$chart->options([
      'maintainAspectRatio'=>false,
      'displayAxes'=>true,
      'responsive' => true,
      'tooltips' => ['enabled'=>true],
      'scales' => [
          'yAxes'=> [[
                      'ticks' => [
                        'beginAtZero' => false,
                        // 'callback' => function(value, index, values){return Number(value.toString())}
                        ],
                      'display'=>true,
                      'gridLines'=> ['display'=> true],
                      'type'=> 'logarithmic'
                    ]],
          'xAxes'=> [[
            'type'=> 'time',
            'time'=> ['displayFormats'=> 'MMM YYYY'],
            // 'ticks' => [
            //   'beginAtZero' => false,
            //   'tickPositions' => $labels[ $site->site_id],
            //   'tickInterval'=> 1,
            //   'ticks.source'=> 'data',
            //   'mode'=> 'linear',
            //   ],
            'distribution'=>'series',
            'display'=>true,
            'gridLines'=> ['display'=> true],
            // // 'time'=>['unit'=>'month']
          ]]
```

Actually xAxes with type as 'time' to considerate date as continuous quantitative variable (also trying ticks.source='data' no effect) console me this error : This method is not implemented
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally used chartjs and delete consoletvs which does not implement all the possibilities of chartjs. I just used type = time and got what I wanted